# JPA - Error saving entities in OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am doing a project for my studies using Spring, Maven, Tomcat, mySQL. I would like to create a website where users can login and update their settings and based on these settings they generate stuff.

At the moment the login is working fine and new users can be registered and saved to the database. Now I created a new entity and made a one to one reletaionship between the two tables - one is the table of the login details like password and username and the other one contains the settings of this user. The issue I am facing:

- I have some textfield and combobox in the UI with vaadin - I populate the fields and click save
- A binder passes these settings to a service that saves the object
- It gets the currently logged in user and loads it from the database

When SQL tries to save the objects it throws error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'user_login_id' doesn't have a
>   default value

Here are the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERLOGIN")
public class UserLogin implements UserDetails {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userlogin")
  private User user;

  public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;

**Other getters and setters**

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "meal")
  private Integer meal;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "userlogin_id")
  private UserLogin userlogin;

  public UserLogin getUserLogin() {
    return userlogin;
  }

  public void setUserLogin(UserLogin userLogin) {
    this.userlogin = userLogin;
    userLogin.setUser(this);

**Other getters and setters**

}
```

The service that saves the settings:

```
@Service
public class AddUserServiceImpl implements AddUserService{

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  private CurrentUserService currentUserService;

  public void saveUser(User userDAO) {

    User user = new User();
    user.setMeal(userDAO.getMeal());
    user.setUserLogin(currentUserService.getCurrentUser());

    userRepository.save(user);

  }

}
```

The repository extends the JPArepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

}
```

And finally the service and the repository that loads the currently logged in user:

```
@Service
public class CurrentUserServiceImpl implements CurrentUserService {

  @Autowired
  UserLoginRepository userLoginRepository;

  public String getCurrentUsername() {
    return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
  }

  public UserLogin getCurrentUser() {
    return userLoginRepository.findByUserName(getCurrentUsername());
  }

}


@Repository
public interface UserLoginRepository extends JpaRepository<UserLogin, 
Integer> {

   @Query("select u from UserLogin u where u.username=:username")
   UserLogin findByUserName( @Param("username") String username);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated I am really new to this topic. **So the main goal is that I want to have a table that stores properties for the currently logged in user - these settings should be able to be updated any time. Is there any best practice for this?**

Thank you!

Comment: check if your `user_login_id` column has `auto increment` flag

Comment: WOW, while I was checking the flag it turned out that the table that I had been using had a lot of keys due to my trials. After I dropped the table user I was able to make the save. However with the posted setup when I clicked on the save again, duplicated entries generated. After a little tweak everything seems to be working. I am still looking forward for other suggestion if this code could be made more better or not! Thank you!